# Why am i not able to see request and response time in jmeter result tree view?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

When i am trying to check my results in result tree view,it does show sampler result but in request it shows"null" and response data is blank.I tried to figure it out but no luck,can you please help me on that?

Comment: Is this an HTTP Request?  Can you post what your Sampler Result shows.

Comment: yes it is http request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a lot of research i found out that jmeter does not save request data ad response time in jtl file by default.To make it work just need to make following changes in jmeter.properties file

jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true

jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true

make sure to uncomment before saving the properties file.